# What is the purpose of the TIdWhoIsServer component from Indy?

Tags: delphi, indy, whois

I saw Indy has a `TIdWhoIsServer` component. What is it used for? Can it be used to do [WhoIs lookups](https://www.whois.com/whois/)? Or what's the purpose of this component?

I tried to find documentation on it, but I couldn't really find anything on it besides the `.pas` file on [GitHub](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/blob/master/Lib/Protocols/IdWhoIsServer.pas) for it.

Can anyone maybe provide some info or documentation on what this component is used for?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very basic local WHOIS server, which clients can connect to and query info for a given domain.  The `OnCommandLookup` event will give you the domain name that the client wants to query.  Whatever info you return from the event will be sent as-is to the client.  Nothing more.  You are responsible for implementing the `OnCommandLookup` event to return whatever info you want for the requested domain. Where that info comes from is up to you.

Comment: Any chance you could add a basic code sample for it?

Comment: There is no example to give. You are given a domain name, and then you provide whatever info you want for it. That's it. Where that info comes from is up to you

Comment: As Remy Lebeau sais there is not much to it. What TIdWhoIsServer should return as response is just a multi-line string containing detailed information about specific domain. There is no specific format in which this information should be formatted in. You can see an example of such returned information by using `TIdWhois` component that you can find in IndyClients  section of component palette. For instance you can call `Memo1.Lines.Add(IdWhois1.WhoIs('google.com'));` to see a returned example. Don't forget to enable Memo's vertical ScrollBar in order to see whole text.